# Why (void*)p instead of static_cast<void*>(p) in C++ standard?

Tags: c++, static-cast

> [ISO/IEC 14882:2020](https://www.iso.org/standard/79358.html)
> 22.2.1.16
> Note 8:
> The default construct in allocator will call `::new ((void*)p) T(args)`, but specialized allocators can choose a different definition.

Would you be so kind as to tell me whether there's any reason it's not `::new (static_cast<void*>(p)) T(args)`?

Comment: The static_cast would fail for const types -- the C style cast is equivalent to const_cast<void *>(static_cast<const void *>(p))

Comment: @ChrisDodd, but if `p` is `const` we would be in trouble in the first place, it would be UB. no? a pure `static_cast<void*>` would catch that.

Comment: `const` objects can still be initialized, it just needs to be possible to do it at compiler time.

Comment: @alfC: anyway const pointer can point to non-const object. and it is modifying const object which is UB.

Comment: @Jarod42 I understand that, but there is no way to know that locally. I found this line to be inconsistent across the cppreference documentation, for example, here (the more correct IMO) `static_cast<void*>` is used: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct

Comment: The cast as written is legal and its meaning is well-defined. Using the long-winded version would obscure the point of the note.